# Sortable handle is not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using sortable widget via jQuery UI. I was be able to get it to work without using the `handle` option. I could not get it work when using the `handle` option to move `li` via `<button>`. What went wrong?

```js
$( ".one" ).sortable({
  handle: ".move"
});

$( ".two" ).sortable({});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<h1>one</h1>
<ul class="one">
  <li>One <button class="move">Move</button></li>
  <li>Two <button class="move">Move</button></li>
  <li>Three <button class="move">Move</button></li>
  <li>Four<button class="move">Move</button></li>
</ul>

<h1>two</h1>
<ul class="two">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

See example on http://jsfiddle.net/80qex6v1/28/

Comment: What do you mean by `I could not get it work`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons don't have the `.handle` class, you need to use `.move` instead. Also note that using a button for this isn't a great idea as they have their own click logic already. I'd suggest using a `div`, or any other non-form input element, instead.

```js
$( ".one" ).sortable({ handle: ".move" });
$( ".two" ).sortable({});
```

```css
.move {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<h1>one</h1>
<ul class="one">
  <li>One
    <div class="move">Move</div>
  </li>
  <li>Two
    <div class="move">Move</div>
  </li>
  <li>Three
    <div class="move">Move</div>
  </li>
  <li>Four
    <div class="move">Move</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1>two</h1>
<ul class="two">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Don't use `<button>` for something that **should not be a button**. It's not good semantic and the button will be ignored by jQueryUI as a handle element - since it's an form action element, not a move handle.